Virtual Dom in react.js
If I have a structure like---
<Header />
<Body />
<footer />

which internally contains html tags like h1, div, ul, li etc
My question is whether Virtual dom is formed by html tags i.e., h1, div, ul, li or react elemnts like - <Header />, <Body /> and <Footer />
This question in my mind arose when I came to know about react's reconciliation algorithm. what does react actually compares? Does it do shallow comparison and checks whether rendered child component like - <Header />, <Body /> is changing? or performs deep comparison and checks if  present in  is changing and updates only that particular div?
********************* EDIT *******************************
so I have this another question-
What if my react structure is like
<Header /> {renderBody()} <Footer /> 
where this renderBody() is a JS funstion which returns some JSX. Now if my component conataining <Header /> {renderBody()} <Footer />   is re-rendered will it always update/re-render renderBody()'s HTML or will perform re-conciliation inside renderBody()'s HTML to update only required tags?

The virtual DOM is made up of the HTML rendered by the React components, not the components themselves.

First: HTML elements are not representative of Virtual Dom. Your Components like "" or Components you Created is The part of Dom Tree.
These Components Return HTML Elements. (You know Everyone I think)
Secondly: You ask Reconciliation Algorithm:
(All Know I Thinks compares the current virtual Dom with the Previous to determine changes )
The process is called Diffing(You can search about it I only know the name of the process). You already know about the shallow comparison.
Third: Reconciliation within renderBody() you provide as a jsx.
React will perform reconciliation within the returned JSX of renderBody()
Also Inside renderBody() it deep checks the changes in which part of renderBody() i.e. your HTML element. react will re_evaluate the function returned value and perform reconciliation within the returned JSX to update only the required parts.

As the name suggests the virtual dom does not contain actual HTMLElements but rather is a deeply nested structure of objects that describe the shape of the elements that will later be rendered in the browser.
// just an example not exactly how
// Reacts VNodes look like
const node = {
  tag: "div",
  attrs: {},
  children: [],
}

At the the application start you have a virtual dom, lets call it t0. On state changes a new virtual dom is created, lets call tn. React then iterates over the virtual nodes in those trees and compares the tag, attrs and children with some assumptions to speed up the whole process. During the comparison an update function is generated that when called will only update the actual elements that need updating.
Edit: This is actually a good read if you want to get a better understanding of Reacts inner workings.

What if my react structure is <Header /> {renderBody()} <Footer />  
this renderBody() is a JS funstion which returns some JSX.
Now if my component conataining <Header /> {renderBody()} <Footer />   is re-rendered will it always update/re-render renderBody() HTML or will perform re-conciliation inside renderBody()'s HTML to update only required tags?

It depends. I assume that your components are wrapped in some other component/tag called e.g C like this: <C><Header/>{renderBody()}<Footer/></C>. Now a rerender was triggered two cases: Cs tag changed means C and every thing in C will be rerendered. Second case C's tag is the same now the nodes for Header, renderBody() and Footer will be compared with their respective old nodes and updated accordingly. In general one can say tag changed means total rerender of said component and its children else only patch attributes and children to which the previous also applies.

so youre saying that react will not only execute but also compare html structure of {renderBody()} on each re-render and update the modified nodes only?

It is not comparing the HTML but rather the old and new virtual dom. But yes to get the new virtual dom all components (which are actually just functions) are called again to get the new vdom.
